# How to bring polygons closer to a point?

Tags: python, postgis, open-source-gis, polygon, algorithm

I have some scattered polygons with a lot of space between them.
I want to make a thematic map but all that white space doesn't look very good, so I want to bring the polygons closer to the center of the area.
Any idea on how to do that in a automatic way? It could be a raw algorithm, postgis query or python function.
Here is an example:

Original:
[image]
Final:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

making the polygons bigger should give the desired effect.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ST_Scale.html

/Nicklas

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you compute the center point and move the polygons towards this point?

Comment: Thats what I want. So far: (st_centroid(st_box2d(st_collect(areas.the_geom))